# insert empty string by adodb prepared statement

Tags: vb6, adodb

In a For Each loop my VB program iterates over an collection.

Inside this loop I'm setting paramaters for the prepared statement.

```
Set param1 = cmd.CreateParameter("sync_id", adChar, adParamInput, Len(sync_id), sync_id)
Set param2 = cmd.CreateParameter("fieldname", adChar, adParamInput, Len(CName), CName)
Set param3 = cmd.CreateParameter("pvname", adChar, adParamInput, Len(pvname), pvname)
Set param4 = cmd.CreateParameter("value", adChar, adParamInput, Len(CNameVal), CNameVal)
```

And then appending them the Command Object.

```
cmd.Parameters.Append param1
cmd.Parameters.Append param2
cmd.Parameters.Append param3
cmd.Parameters.Append param4
```

When `CNameVal` (`param4`) is empty VB gives me an error: The paramater object is not defined properly.

I tried to solve this by checking `CNameVal` before creating the parameter:

```
If CNameVal = Empty Then
    Set param4 = cmd.CreateParameter("value", adEmpty, adParamInput)
    'Set param4 = cmd.CreateParameter("value")
    'Set param4 = cmd.CreateParameter("value", adEmpty, adParamInput, Len(CNameVal), CNameVal)
Else
    Set param4 = cmd.CreateParameter("value", adChar, adParamInput, Len(CNameVal), CNameVal)
End If
```

Neither of those lines solve problem. Any help appreciated!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Len(Empty) = 0`, which leads to an error. String length cannot be `0`.
Correct practice here is to provide actual fixed length set in the database, not the length of the current string. I also doubt you need `adChar`, you probably meant `adVarChar`.

<s>Your `If` doesn't work because `CNameVal = Empty` is never going to be `True`. The correct way of checking for Empty is `IsEmpty(CNameVal)`.</s>

Comment: `Len(Empty) = 0` was indeed the problem! I now manually set the length to 1 when length = 0. What you say about `CNameVal = Empty` is not the correct way: in my case `IsEmpty(CNameVal)` is never going to be `True` and `CNameVal = Empty` or `CNameVal = ""` is... Is that weird? :)

Comment: @ZacL I was wrong, you can compare something with `Empty` (you can't with `Null`). But `Empty` is a special value within `Variant` data type, and you are using it to tell if the string has zero length. This works because VB handles the conversion for you so that `Empty = ""` yields `True` despite they are different things. For your code to be more clear about its goals, it's advisable you check that `Len(a_string) = 0` rather than `a_string = Empty`.